# I'm trying to reduce ten columns of Excel formulas into one cell with one large, nested command if possible

Tags: excel, nested, formula

[Weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bkuI.jpg)

I have built a tab in an Excel spreadsheet that uses base data from 6 columns and then formulas in 9 additional columns that determine the final result in another column, which then gets copied into another cell on another tab (see 'weights' picture at top of this post):

The base data is in 6 columns A-F and has 729 rows - each column has a certain weight (30%, 20%, 20%, 10%, 15%, 5%).  Each cell is either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, N/A, or blank.  The goal is to look for N/A or blanks and then redistribute the weight for those categories to the remaining non-N/A and non-blank categories, so if the 20% column was N/A and the other 5 columns were 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, I would add 4% to each of the 5 scored categories to calculate the final score.  Everything works great but I am interested in doing everything in one column after the 6 base columns.  I start by converting N/A to 0 and then handle things in multiple columns by doing this:

In Column G, I get the total weight of the columns with N/A or 0:

=SUMIF(A2:F2,0,$A$729:$F$729)

Then in Column H, I get the number of columns that the weight percentage in Column G will get distributed to:

=COUNTIF(A2:F2,">0")

Then in Column I, I calculate the percentage to be added to the remaining columns:

=IF(H2=0,0,SUM(G2/H2))

Then in Columns J-O, I calculate the new weight percentages for each weight (the original weight percentages are in cells H2-H7 on a different tab called 'Controls':

=SUM(Controls!$H$2+$I2) is for Column J, =SUM(Controls!$H$3+$I2) is for Column K, etc.

Then finally I calculate the 'new' score with the 'new' weights.  If there were no N/A or 0's, it keeps the original overall score and if not it multiples the score in a cell (1,2,3,4,5) by the new weight and adds the six totals together:

=IF(H2=6,Q2,SUM(A2*J2)+(B2*K2)+(C2*L2)+(D2*M2)+(E2*N2)+(F2*O2))

It all works great, but how can do what I'm doing in 10 columns with just one statement in one cell?  I'm assuming there are lots of elegant references and nesting required but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `BYROW()` function with `SUMIFS()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this step by step:

e.g.

cell (G2) `=SUMIF(A2:F2,0,$A$729:$F$729)`

cell (H2) `= COUNTIF(A2:F2,">0")`

cell (I2) `=IF(H2=0,0,SUM(G2/H2))`

In cell I2 replace the cell references of G2 and H2 with the formula expression of the respective cells.

More elegant with LET:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999

Comment: In I2, you may want to just G2/H2 without SUM() and alternatively IFERROR(G2/H2,0) is little shorter than the IF clause